# Session code not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, session

i am trying to develop a login form so i got online and picked a code. i made a database called "company" with a table "login" having fields; Id, username and password. I have saved some entries in the table.

when i try to login i get a response; *The page isn't redirecting properly;
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.*

and i dont know whats wrong.
Below is my code:
index.php

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>PHP Login Session Example</h1>
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "company");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose

// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session

} else {
$error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","company");
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysqli_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

thank you.

Comment: did you check whether you gave correct path for header location

Comment: yes, all files are in the same folder /var/www/html

Comment: The `header()` function does not stop execution of the script it is in. It just sends a header instructing the browser to load a different page. So an `exit;` after a `header()` redirect is always sensible `if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php"); exit;
}`

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Everything about this code is *extremely concerning* and you should avoid using it at all costs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is that in profile.php you have the arguments to `mysqli_query` in the wrong order which means profile.php redirects to index.php which sees `$_SESSION['login_user']` set so it redirects to profile.php which then redirects to index.php etc. etc. etc.

Comment: As @tadman points out, if you'd used the OO form of the interface it would have been much harder to make this error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I have connected to another table with more fields thats is; id, firstname, username and password.

I edited the session.php and changed the mysqli_query using Firstname where Username is $user_check. Im now printing the name of the logged in user.

Thank you guys.

Comment: If this code is for academic purposes then hopefully you've learned something. If this is for production use with actual users there's a number of serious problems that remain unresolved, so I'd proceed with extreme caution.

Comment: Im learning but intend to build some application. Actually, i will be very pleased when any noticed serious problems in my code mentioned. That way i will be able to learn more. Thank you @tadman

Comment: Stay safe, it's a nasty world out there on the internet.